# couldnot read script react.gradle it doesnot exist

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I am getting error like

> couldnot read script
>   'C:\Users\sys\Downloads\insta-snap-master\insta-snap-master\node_module\react-native\react.gradle
>   open file' as it doesnot exist.

Why I am getting this error how to fix this and I am trying to run github code, please anyone can help me.

This is my `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile


apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"


def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false


def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.insta"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
    }
}
splits {
    abi {
        reset()
        enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
        universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
        include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
    }
}
// applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
        // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
        def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
        def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
        if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
            output.versionCodeOverride =
                    versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
        }
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile project(':react-native-video')
compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
compile project(':react-native-camera')
compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
from configurations.compile
into 'libs'
}
```

Thank you very much for your time and assistance in this matter.

Comment: I'm seeing the same symptom. Did you figure this out?